# Rigify: can't apply current pose as the rest pose

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

I have a model rigged with Rigify. I pose it as:

[image]

And `Pose -> Apply -> Apply as Rest Pose`. But what it does is the opposite of what I expected. It just resets the pose.

[image]

`Apply as Rest Pose` works for my manually rigged model, but not for Rigified one. What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that one can only use `Apply Selected as Rest Pose` with Rigify, but not `Apply as Rest Pose`, since it applies some mechanism bones(?) too and ruins the pose. Only control bones should be applied.